# Categoria e subcategoria na listagem PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
public function listar($tipo=null){
    $this->db->select('p1.*, p2.titulo as subcategoria, p2.id as id2');
    $this->db->join("produto_categoria as p2", "p1.id=p2.id_categoria", "LEFT");
    $consulta = $this->db->get('produto_categoria as p1')->result();
    return $consulta;
}
```

Minha Tabela
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu resultado atual
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso que, ao listar, cada subcategoria fique dentro da sua categoria, exemplo: Cílios > fio a fio, Cílios > 3D. E as demais que não tem subcategoria, liste apenas. O que eu fiz errado?

Listagem

```
<table class="table table-hover m-b-0 c_list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Cod</th>                                    
            <th>Titulo</th>                                    
            <th width="10%">Ações</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach($lista as $s_lista){ ?> 
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p class="id"><?php echo $s_lista->id; ?></p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php if($s_lista->subcategoria==""){ ?>
                    <strong>Principal Raiz</strong> <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <?php echo $s_lista->titulo; ?> <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>

                <?php } ?>
               <?php echo $s_lista->subcategoria; ?>
            </td>                                   
            <td>                                            
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" title="Editar"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                <button type="button" data-type="confirm" class="btn btn-danger js-sweetalert" title="Deletar"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Resultado esperado:

```
> Cilios 
> Cilios > 3D
> Cilios > Fio a Fio
> Pentes
> Toucas
```

Answer (score 1):

Cara mudei um pouco sua query o único "problema" é que o CI não trabalha muito bem com UNION por isso eu montei ela e usei o `$this->db->query()`.

```
public function listar($tipo=null){
    $query = "SELECT Id, IdCategoria, Titulo, Ordem, SubCategoria, Id2 FROM
            (
            SELECT id, IdCategoria, Ordem, Titulo, NULL AS SubCategoria, NULL AS Id2 FROM produtocategoria
            UNION
            SELECT p1.id, p1.IdCategoria, p1.Ordem, p1.Titulo, p2.Titulo, p2.id FROM produtocategoria AS p1 LEFT JOIN produtocategoria AS p2 ON p1.id = p2.idcategoria ORDER BY Id, SubCategoria
            ) AS tab
            WHERE IdCategoria = 0"

    return $this->db->query($query)->result();
}
```

Precisa mudar os nomes das colunas para se enquadrar no seu caso mas a lógica é essa. Segue resultado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]